# When is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}] /p\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ and p be an odd prime. Show that $R/pR$ is a field if and only if $p \equiv  5$, $7$ ($\textrm{mod}$ $8$).

I've already proved that $R$ is an euclidean domain, thus a DIP and I've already proved that if $p \equiv 1$, $3 (\textrm{mod}$ $8)$, then $R/pR$ is not a field.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: How did you handle the case $p\equiv 3\bmod 8 $?

Answer (score 3):

Relating square roots to roots of unity is the key to quadratic reciprocity.

For $p$ odd. Let $k = \Bbb{F}_p(i,\sqrt2)$ and $\zeta_8 = \frac{\sqrt2+i\sqrt2}{2}\in k$ which is a **primitive $8$th root of unity**.

Then $\sqrt{-2}= \zeta_8-\zeta_8^{-1}$.

It is in $\Bbb{F}_p$ iff $$\zeta_8^p-\zeta_8^{-p}=(\zeta_8-\zeta_8^{-1})^p=\sqrt{-2}^p=\sqrt{-2}=\zeta_8-\zeta_8^{-1}$$ which happens iff $\zeta_8^p = \zeta_8$ or $-\zeta_8^{-1}$ iff $p\equiv ... \bmod 8$.

From there we know when $x^2+2\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible thus when $$\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]/(p)=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+2)/(p)=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+2)$$ is a field.